# Use TFS to go back to Default

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs

I have made some changes and saved the sourcecode in my client computer but the code is not checked in.

I want to go back to default that I had the latest sourcecode before I made some changes.

It is one file only. How should I do it?

I'm using VS Community 2013 with Team foundation Server.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried doing an "Undo" from Pending Changes in the Team Explorer Window.

Comment: not yet.. I have not tried yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use "Undo" from pending changes in the Team Explorer Window.